# I have updated my android studio, previously that code was running now its not. What to do

Tags: android

I have made a phone call recorder which can record all incoming and outgoing calls it was running very well on previous android studio, but as I updated android studio, application is crashing while making calls. I have updated all the SDK, Gradle files, properties but still not working. Below is the PhoneStateReceiver.java file and error screenshot. Suggestions are welcome.

> ERROR LOG SCREENSHOT - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpeIy.png

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        Boolean switchCheckOn = pref.getBoolean("switchOn", true);
        if (switchCheckOn) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Receiver Start");

//            boolean callWait=pref.getBoolean("recordStarted",false);
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    Log.d(TAG, " onReceive: " + state);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Call detected(Incoming/Outgoing) " + state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (extras != null) {
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        Log.d(TAG1, " Inside " + state);
                    /*int j=pref.getInt("numOfCalls",0);
                    pref.edit().putInt("numOfCalls",++j).apply();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: num of calls "+ pref.getInt("numOfCalls",0));*/
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)/*&& pref.getInt("numOfCalls",1)==1*/) {

                        int j = pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 0);
                        pref.edit().putInt("numOfCalls", ++j).apply();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: num of calls " + pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 0));

                        Log.d(TAG1, " recordStarted in offhook: " + recordStarted);
                        Log.d(TAG1, " Inside " + state);
                        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        Log.d(TAG1, " Phone Number in receiver " + phoneNumber);
                        if (pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 1) == 1) {
                            Intent reivToServ = new Intent(context, RecorderService.class);
                            reivToServ.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);

                            Log.d("fatal", "onReceive: " + reivToServ.toString());

                            //name=new CommonMethods().getContactName(phoneNumber,context);
                            int serialNumber = pref.getInt("serialNumData", 1);
                            new DatabaseManager(context).addCallDetails(new CallDetails(serialNumber, phoneNumber, new CommonMethods().getTIme(), new CommonMethods().getDate()));

                            List<CallDetails> list = new DatabaseManager(context).getAllDetails();
                            for (CallDetails cd : list) {
                                String log = "Serial Number : " + cd.getSerial() + " | Phone num : " + cd.getNum() + " | Time : " + cd.getTime1() + " | Date : " + cd.getDate1();
                                Log.d("Database ", log);
                            }
                            //recordStarted=true;
                            pref.edit().putInt("serialNumData", ++serialNumber).apply();
                            pref.edit().putBoolean("recordStarted", true).apply();
                        }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        int k = pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 1);
                        pref.edit().putInt("numOfCalls", --k).apply();
                        int l = pref.getInt("numOfCalls", 0);
                        Log.d(TAG1, " Inside " + state);
                        recordStarted = pref.getBoolean("recordStarted", false);
                        Log.d(TAG1, " recordStarted in idle :" + recordStarted);
                        if (recordStarted && l == 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG1, " Inside to stop recorder " + state);

                            context.stopService(new Intent(context, RecorderService.class));

                            pref.edit().putBoolean("recordStarted", false).apply();
                        }

                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing??

Comment: In the screenshot, there are only warnings, not  an error

Comment: There are no errors in the screenshot

Comment: Show your Logcat errors!! The image you provided is just a code

Comment: @RahulKhurana I have updated the image. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @VivekMishra I have updated it. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @PrajwalW Sorry for the inconvenience. Have updated the image. have a look

Comment: click on the logcat error on MEdiarecorder and check which line gives the error in your code.

Comment: it is not an issue with Android Studio. You must have updated TargetSdkVersion or tested with some other device.

Comment: You are definitely not stopping the media recorder properly!! show the code which the logcat points to

Comment: @RahulKhurana Android version is 7.1.1 ,tagetSDk - 28 , minSDK - 19

Comment: what is at RecorderService.java at line 65??

Comment: @RahulKhurana it worked. Thank you. Now i want to upload all the recordings on firebase. Previously was using Sqlite db. Can you help me out.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020001/4079010/